# Tried rooting my Nexus 5, did something wrong and now it is stuck rebooting

Tags: rooting, nexus-5

So, today I tried rooting my Nexus 5 with Nexus Root Toolkit. I have done it before, but I did something wrong. After rooting it, I had to reboot it, but it got stuck in the part with all the circles with colors, before it says ANDROID and the phone starts. I researched, and it seems I have to reinstall the ROM with the Nexus Toolkit. It says the phone has to be completely turned off, so I have to wait until my battery dies or I do a battery pull. Any solutions? My phone was at 20 percent when this happened, so, how long will it take for the battery to die?

Answer (score 2):

Wiping cache normally fixes boot-loop issues. Before you proceed you will need to install [ADB](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Adb) on your system.

1. Connect your device to your PC using a USB cable
2. Open a terminal and enter `adb reboot recovery`
3. Use the volume buttons to scroll to "wipe data/factory reset" and press the Power button to select it.
4. Scroll down to "Yes - erase all user data" and press the Power button to select it.
5. Reboot the phone.

*If your phone becomes unresponsive at any point during these steps, you can restart it by holding down the Power button for several seconds.*